# Calculate median of pdf using NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics

I was trying to compute the median of a pdf using NSolve, defined such that
$$ \int_{0}^{\rm median}p(x)dx = \frac{1}{2} $$ but NSolve seems unhappy about solving for an upper limit of an integral. A simple example:

```
F[x_] := 2*Pi^(-1/2)*NIntegrate[Exp[-y^2], {y, 0, x}]
NSolve[F[x] == 0.5, x]
```

This gives the warning

```
NIntegrate::nlim: y = x is not a valid limit of integration.
```

I find this surprising - what is causing NSolve to not be able to handle this and what is a workaround? Obviously in this example Mathematica can symbolically integrate to give ${\rm erf}$ and then reports

```
NSolve[Erf[x] == 0.5]

During evaluation of In[30]:= NSolve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by NSolve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

{{x -> 0.476936}}
```

but symbolically integrating and then using inverse functions seems huge overkill for what could in this case easily be achieved by a few function calls along with interval bisection.

Comment: What about something like the following:  `dist = ProbabilityDistribution[2 \[Pi]^(-1/2) Exp[-y^2], {y, 0, \[Infinity]}]; NSolve[CDF[dist, y] == 1/2, y]`.

Comment: @JimB yes that works in this case. I'd still really like to know what NSolve is doing since I can't seem to get it to play nicely with NIntegrate in a variety of contexts.

Comment: Since the definition of `F` uses a numeric technique (i.e., `NIntegrate`), the argument to `F` should be restricted to numeric values: `F[x_?NumericQ] := ...` You will then get the expected results.

Comment: What in the documentation for `NSolve` suggests it should work with `NIntegrate`?  (It doesn't.) Then look up `FindRoot`, as @cvgmt shows.

Comment: This is not any [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median): in the case under consideration the median equals zero.

Comment: @user64494 Not true.  The pdf integrates to 1 over 0 to $\infty$.  It is not a normal distribution but rather a half-normal distribution with parameter $\sqrt\pi$.

Comment: This should be noticed in the question.

Comment: @JimB: BTW, `dist = ProbabilityDistribution[
  \[Pi]^(-1/2) Exp[-y^2], {y, 0, \[Infinity]}]; NSolve[
 CDF[dist, y] == 1/4, y]` results in meaningless `{{y -> 0.476936}}`

Comment: @user64494 I get `{{y -> 0.225312}}` (Mathematica 12.3.1.0, Windows 10).  And `CDF[dist, 0.2253120550121781]` gets me 0.25 (the correct value).

Answer (score 5):

We can replace `NIntegrate` by `Integrate` and use `FindRoot`.

```
F[x_] := 2*Pi^(-1/2)*Integrate[Exp[-y^2], {y, 0, x}]
FindRoot[F[x] == 0.5, {x, 0}]
```

> `{x -> 0.476936}`

Another way is again use `NDSolve`.

```
NDSolve[{F'[x] == 2*Pi^(-1/2)*Exp[-x^2], F[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[F[x] == 0.5, {Print[x], "StopIntegration"}]}, 
 F[x], {x, 0, ∞}]
```

> `0.476936`

Comment: `F[x_?NumericQ] := 2*Pi^(-1/2)*NIntegrate[Exp[-y^2], {y, 0, x}];
FindRoot[F[x] == 0.5, {x, 1}]` also works in 12.3.1, producing `{x -> 0.476936}` and "NIntegrate::nlim: y = x is not a valid limit of integration."

Comment: I agree with some other users that replacing F[x_?NumericQ] in my original suggestion (ie using NIntegrate and NSolve) seems to work in this case. Is there any difference between using NSolve and FindRoot?